# Private function error with PHPUnit testing

Tags: php, function, class, phpunit, private

I am getting the following error in my PHPunit test

```
Warning: Invalid callback Vc_Manager::__sleep, cannot access private method Vc_Manager::__sleep()
```

This is caused because the function __sleep() is private and the __contruct() function for the class is also private.

How can I using this function in my phpunit testing without turning the function public?

Full code:

```
require_once('../splitTestNew.php');



class SplitTestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{


    public function setUp(){

    }
    public function tearDown(){ }
    /**
     * @runInSeparateProcess
     */
    public function testDefaultParameterValues()
    {

        $obj = new BSSplitTest();
        $this->assertTrue($obj->params['A'] == 50);
        $this->assertTrue($obj->params['B'] == 50);
        $this->assertTrue($obj->params['SplitCookieA'] == 'ACounter');
        $this->assertTrue($obj->params['SplitCookieB'] == 'BCounter');
        $this->assertTrue($obj->params['TableA'] == 'counter_a');
        $this->assertTrue($obj->params['TableB'] == 'counter_b');

    }
```

Comment: When testing libraries that I share the code with other modules in my application, I use Reflection (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to validate internal variables or function processes to ensure that my library code works as I expect. Then my application testing uses the public methods to work with the library.

Answer (score 1):

If your constructor is private then you can't have

```
 $obj = new BSSplitTest();
```

That implies your constructor is public, you'll need a static factory constructor.

```
 $obj = BSSplitTest::getInstance(); //or createInstance if not singleton
```

Answer (score 0):

We NEVER test private methods, it doesn't make any sense. You either need to make the function public or test functions that use the private method.

Also, if the constructor is private too, you first need to make an instance of the class (for instance using Factory pattern) and then invoke a function.

Comment: The private function itself is not being testing but the required file at the top also includes the file wp-load.php to query post types. This contains private functions from the Visual Composer plugin for wordpress. It is therefore not possible to change the function to public